# How to create random vectors of another vector?

Tags: r

I am performing calculations with constants and vectors (approximate length = 100) for which I need to simulate normal distributions N (with rnorm). For constants (K, with standard deviation = KU) I use rnorm() in the standard way:

```
    K  <- 2
    KU <- 0.2
    set.seed(123)
    KN <- rnorm(n = 3, mean = K, sd = KU)
```

what provides a vector of length 3 (KN):

```
    [1] 1.887905 1.953965 2.311742
```

Now, I need to do the same thing with a vector (V, standard deviation VU). My first guess is to use:

```
    V  <- c(1, 2, 3)
    VU <- 0.1 * V
    set.seed(123)
    VN <- rnorm(3, V, VU)
```

but only a vector of 3 elements is produced, one for each vector element:

```
    [1] 0.9439524 1.9539645 3.4676125
```

This is actually the first simulation of the vector, but I need 3 times this vector. One solution is to create 9 numbers, but VN is a vector of 9 elements:

```
    [1] 0.9439524 1.9539645 3.4676125 1.0070508 2.0258575 3.5145195 1.0460916 1.7469878 2.7939441
```

not 3 vectors of 3 elements. What I want is VN =

```
    [1] 0.9439524 1.0070508 1.0460916
    [2] 1.9539645 2.0258575 1.7469878
    [3] 3.4676125 3.5145195 2.7939441
```

so, VN are 3 vectors which I can subsequently use in other calculations, such as KN * VN. The solution that I have found is:

```
    set.seed(123)
    VN <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(rnorm(3 * length(V), V, VU), nrow = length(V))))
```

but in my opinion this is a rather cumbersome expression (which I need to repeat several times in different places with rather long variable names). Is there a simpler way in base R to produce random vectors? I would like to see something like:

```
    VN <- rnorm.vector(3, V, VU)
```

Comment: You can use `mapply` `mapply(rnorm, n  = 3, mean = V, sd = VU)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `replicate`

```
set.seed(123)
replicate(3, rnorm(3, V, VU))
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] 0.9439524 1.007051 1.046092
#[2,] 1.9539645 2.025858 1.746988
#[3,] 3.4676125 3.514519 2.793944
```

---

Or it could be

```
mapply(rnorm, n = 3, mean = V, sd = VU)
```

Comment: Both answers are simple and elegant. I have done some benchmarking and mapply() is about 25% faster than replicate. As I need to produce many iterations, I will use mapply().

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @akrun's great options, you may also use something slightly simpler than your approach:

```
matrix(rnorm(n * length(V), V, VU), nrow = n, byrow = TRUE)
#           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 0.9439524 1.953965 3.467612
# [2,] 1.0070508 2.025858 3.514519
# [3,] 1.0460916 1.746988 2.793944
```

or also the `MASS` package with `mvrnorm` letting to sample from a multivariate normal distribution:

```
library(MASS)
mvrnorm(n, VU, diag(VU))
#            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  0.6650715  0.37923044 0.05590089
# [2,]  0.2574341  0.24949882 0.97045721
# [3,] -0.5218990 -0.04857971 0.49707815
```

where

```
diag(VU)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  0.1  0.0  0.0
# [2,]  0.0  0.2  0.0
# [3,]  0.0  0.0  0.3
```

The latter option is the way to go in case you want the variance-covariance matrix not to be diagonal.